# Code for counting frequency of element in array not working

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to find the frequency of elements in an array. I have found lots of programs on Google that can do just this, but I can't get them to count right for my array.

This is the code I use:

```cpp
#include <iostrem>
#include <cmath>

const int nmax = 50;

int main() {
    int afk[nmax], count;
    
    const int N = 40;
    int dn[N] = { 6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        afk[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (dn[i] == dn[j]) {
                count++;
                afk[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (afk[i] != 0) afk[i] = count;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        if (afk[i] != 0) {
            cout << endl << i << " | " << afk[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
0 | 2
1 | 13
2 | 5
4 | 5
5 | 6
```

But I know this is worng and the right answer is

```
0 | 8
1 | 13
2 | 5
3 | 6  
4 | 1
5 | 5
6 | 2
```

So the code only gets the frequency of elemnet 1 and 2 right.

Can anyone tell what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What were the results of your own debugging so far?

Comment: Would you like to talk through the logic why do think your code should work?

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and perform one pass, counting directly in `afk` as you find each value. Something like `for(int i=0; i<N; i++){ afk[dn[i]]++; }`

Comment: I tried to beat your code into compliable condition, but when I was done I couldn't reproduce your problem. I got a totally different wrong answer. Further debugging would be pointless, I'd likely be trying to solve the wrong bug, so I'm out. Recommendation: back up your code and make a [mre]. If the MRE doesn't help you find the problem, it usually does, add the MRE to the question with an edit.

Comment: What is `nmax`?

Comment: A number >= `N` or say hello to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *counting* the frequencies just fine (well, not as efficiently as you could be), but you are not *displaying* them correctly.

The `afk[]` array is storing each number's frequency at the same index as its first occurrence in the `dn[]` array.

In your final display loop, you are printing the loop counter `i` itself instead of printing the number at the `i`'th index of the `dn[]` array. So, if you change this:

```cpp
cout << endl << i << " | " << afk[i];
```

To this:

```cpp
cout << endl << dn[i] << " | " << afk[i];
```

Then you will get a more meaningful result:

```
6 | 2
1 | 13
2 | 5
5 | 5
3 | 6
```

Note that the frequencies of `0` and `4` are missing, though.  The first occurrence of `0` in the `dn[]` array is at index 7, and the first occurrence of `4` is at index 36.  But your display loop stops after index 6, which is why it does not display the frequencies of `0` and `4`.  You would need to loop over the entire `afk[]` array to fix that, then you will see the missing entries:

```
6 | 2
1 | 13
2 | 5
5 | 5
3 | 6
0 | 8
4 | 1
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/TwAigh)

However, the results are not sorted by number, as you want.  To fix that, you will have to either:

- sort the `dn[]` array before counting its frequencies (which, incidentally, will help make counting easier).
- change the `afk[]` array to hold a `struct` type that contains `int number` and `int frequency` members, and then you can sort `afk[]` on `number` after counting the frequencies.
- if `nmax` is greater than the largest number in the `dn[]` array (ie, `> 6` in this case), then your counting loop can simply use the number stored at `dn[i]` as the index into `afk[]` rather than using `i` as the index. Then your display loop can simply display the `afk[]` array as-is (I *suspect* this is what you originally meant to do). [Demo](https://ideone.com/AmJrmK)

---

In which case, it would be far easier to count the frequencies using a `std::map` instead, and let it handle the counting and sorting for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, int> afk;
    
    int dn[40] = {6, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 3};

    for(auto number : dn){
        afk[number]++;
    }

    for(auto &p : afk){
        cout << p.first << " | " << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

```
0 | 8
1 | 13
2 | 5
3 | 6
4 | 1
5 | 5
6 | 2
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Ou5TbO)

Comment: This code works perfectly, I'm just gonna copy our code. Thank you!

Comment: @SímunPauliPálsson do your best to understand it. Ask more questions if you have to. If you don't understand and it shows up on an exam or some other practical situation, you'll wish you'd done more than just copy.